# mySalesforce app functionality

Tags: mobile

Does anyone know what options there are for customizing the mySalesforce app?

Is it just the salesforce app with a customer's own branding? Does it work with communities? Will this make the mobile SDKs irrelevant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/salesforce1_branded_apps) is probably the best link to answer your first question, and here's the best quote from it

> "Well, it’s identical to the Salesforce mobile app, but it’s
>   better... because it’s truly yours. It’s a fully branded version of
>   your Salesforce mobile implementation. Your app icon, your name, your
>   colors, and—most important—your very own listing in Google Play™ and
>   the Apple App Store®."

I'd take this with a pinch-of-salt, as "fully branded" does not mean you have full control over the UI, you only have as much as you'd get with the Salesforce Mobile App.

2) Communities should be able to use mySalesforce in the same way as you can use the existing Salesforce App; which means there is some support but there are too some [limitations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_access_in_salesforce1.htm&type=5).

3) Short answer, nope. The Salesfoce Mobile SDK provides a basis for true custom apps. These true custom apps provide scope for additional possibilities above the mySalesforce, which include (but not limited to);

- 100% custom UI
- 100% custom UX
- Access to hardware APIs that aren't available in mySalesforce
- Comprehensive support for full network resilient and offline conditions

Comment: I did get confirmation from Salesforce that communities are not supported, it really is just a branded Salesforce1 app